# c++ member function name ambiguous with standard c library

Tags: c++, c

The following is my sample code

in member function `foo()` which needs to use the standard c library's `exit()` to terminate
the process, but it has ambiguous naming error with the member function `int CFoo::exit(void)` at compiling time.

Is anyway can avoid this problem?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

class CFoo
{

public:

    void foo(void)
    {
        exit(0); // needs to use standard libc to exit process
    }

    void exit(void)
    {
        printf("exit\n");
    }
};

int main()
{

    CFoo obj;

    obj.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `exit(0)` with `::exit(0)`. This will force it to use the globally scoped version of `exit`.

Comment: Or include `<cstdlib>` and use `std::exit`. I'm not sure if it is guaranteed that C library functions be placed in the global namespace, although compilers tend to do it as a matter of practicality.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally bad practice to have naming conflicts with reserved functions.

I'd recommend renaming `exit` perhaps as the destructor.

You may be able to prefix with the classname to avoid the compile error: `CFoo::exit(void)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `stdlib.h` to `cstdlib` and use `std::exit(0)` to use standard library function.
When using c libraries inside C++, Use C++ headers (those start with c prefix) instead of ".h" which is deprecated.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>

class CFoo
{

    public:

   void foo(void)
   {
       std::exit(0); // needs to use standard libc to exit process
   }

   void exit(void)
   {
       printf("exit\n");
   }
};

int main()
{

   CFoo obj;
   obj.foo();
}
```